# Is there a way to turn off auto save?

Tags: starcraft-2

I'd rather just control my own saves manually than having to wait for the game to auto save at specified checkpoints and confuse my load list.  Is there a way to disable auto save?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the problem -- Auto saves should already be located in their own folder.

[image]

As long as you don't blindly click "Load Last Saved Game", you should have full, un-confused control over which game you are loading.

Comment: I see... but part of the issue was that I don't like to wait while the game is saving.  Does this mean that there actually isn't a way to auto save?

Comment: @PileOfDuty Not that I could find.